# In Memoriam: Tom Petty

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Singer/Songwriter Tom Petty, perhaps best known for performing the closing song in [*Stargate: Atlantis* episode "Vegas"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LjfwgqN_hg), has passed away.

Answer (score 12):

I'll remember him most fondly as the Mayor of Bridge City in the blockbuster film [The Postman](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119925/).

[image]

Apparently he was also a [singer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Petty_discography).

Comment: Gah, this film was so terrible! Book better but still not great.